# Nginx static file specific to subdomain

Tags: regex, node.js, nginx

I have a NodeJs application running on localhost:8000 and am using Nginx as proxy server. This is the only application running on Nodejs while other applications are PHP based.

I am trying to set a proxy in Nginx to redirect all request from "http://localhost/NodeApp/" to "http://localhost:8000/". Only the css/js/images files from this nodeapp should be fetched directly by Nginx. All other requests are directed to Apache server. The Nginx config is like this -

```
#Need to modify this code to fetch static files for NodeApp only!
location ~ ^/(uploads/|vendor/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
  root /var/www/NodeApp/public;
  access_log off;
}

location /NodeApp/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

Above Nginx config breaks other applications as it looks for static files in NodeApp public folder. How should I modify above config to work only for "localhost/NodeApp/"

I tried below config but that breaks the NodeApp static folder has sub-folders-
    /public/js/bootstrap/
    /public/js/datepicker/
    /public/css/bootstrap/
    /public/css/datepicker/
    /public/uploads/pdf/
    /public/images/

```
location /NodeApp/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://OneDesktop/;
    alias /var/www/NodeApp/public/;
}
```

Any advice? I tried many things but no luck!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Node application is not just the one URI, it is a collection of URIs. The cleanest approach is to modify the application itself so that it lives below `/NodeApp/` (including where it pulls in its static resources).

With the current situation, the resource files for the Node application overlap the namespace of the resource files for other hosted applications, and it is difficult to define rules to separate these two overlapping namespaces.

One (less than ideal) option would be to ask `nginx` to serve the files from one document root, then defer to another document root if the original file does not exist.

Something like this:

```
root /other/application/root;

location / {
    index ...;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location @other {
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ... 
}

location ~ ^/(uploads/|vendor/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
    root /var/www/NodeApp/public;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri @other;
}

location /NodeApp/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

The `location @other` block will serve static files from the other application root. The PHP location block is the first regex `location` so that it takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Appreciate your answer. Will try the nginx config settings tonight and update here again. 

One question on implementing application under /NodeApp/ itself - I am using **"hackathon-starter"** which recommends putting static files under public/js, public/css etc. However, in that application, express handles the static files. What you are suggesting is not to take this approach? Am i doing something wrong as could find anything similar anywhere on internet.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the previous comment - Am i doing something wrong as could **not** find anything similar anywhere on internet

Comment: Sorry, I was taking about URLs and not physical directories. Where your files live at the moment is perfectly OK. The problem is keeping their URLs separate from the URLs of the PHP applications. Running disparate applications within the same domain often requires creative solutions which are not addressed in single application tutorials.